# PyGears How to make counter

Tags: python, pygears

I want to make a counter which can start counting at posedge of a specific signal (enable signal). And once it counts to 256, stop counting, set the counter to 0 and output something.

Answer (score 1):

When designing with PyGears, you should try to think more in terms of functions (although asynchronous) that are being invoked by receiving commands via input interfaces. Instead of thinking of the `enable` signal that triggers the counter, try to think of a counter you described as a function that receives a number to count to as an input command and outputs something once it's done counting. There are two ways we could go about implementing this:

1. An async gear, in which we write procedural code to describe the logic

   ```
    from pygears import gear, sim
    from pygears.typing import Uint
    from pygears.sim import log
    from pygears.lib import once, qrange


    @gear
    async def counter(cmd: Uint, *, something) -> b'type(something)':
        async with cmd as c:
            async for i in qrange(c):
                pass

            yield something


    @gear
    async def collect(data):
        async with data as d:
            log.info(f'Got something: {d}')


    once(val=256) \
        | counter(something=Uint[8](2)) \
        | collect

    sim()
   ```

   Here, the `counter` has an interface called `cmd`, where a number of cycles to count is received, and a compile time parameter called `something`, which will be sent through the output interface once the counting is done. In the body of the function, we first wait for the input command to arrive: `async with cmd as c:`, next we wait for the counter to finish and finally we output `something`. `qrange` is a builtin gear and you are welcome to inspect its implementation here: [rng.py](https://github.com/bogdanvuk/pygears/blob/master/pygears/lib/rng.py)

   Then there's the `collect` gear which simply prints out whatever it receives. Finally, we generate the command for the `counter` using `once`, and feed the output of the `counter` to the `collect` module. When `sim()` is invoked, we get the following output showing that `collect` got `something` in the cycle 255:

   ```
    0                      [INFO]: -------------- Simulation start --------------  
    255             /collect [INFO]: Got something: u8(2)  
    256                      [INFO]: ----------- Simulation done ---------------  
    256                      [INFO]: Elapsed: 0.03
   ```
2. We could use a hierarchical gear to connect existing builtin modules to achieve the same thing:

   ```
    from pygears import gear, sim
    from pygears.typing import Uint
    from pygears.sim import log
    from pygears.lib import once, qrange, when


    @gear
    def counter(cmd: Uint, *, something):
        last = qrange(cmd)['eot']

        return when(last, something)


    @gear
    async def collect(data):
        async with data as d:
            log.info(f'Got something: {d}')


    once(val=256) \
        | counter(something=Uint[8](2)) \
        | collect

    sim()
   ```

   Everything is pretty much the same, except that the `counter` isn't defined with the `async` keyword, meaning that it is a hierarchical gear and only describes interconnection between its submodules. The `qrange` gear outputs both the iterator and a flag, called `eot` (for end-of-transaction), which marks the last count. We feed `eot` (via `eot` variable) to the `when` gear that will only output `something` when it sees value `True` on `eot` interface.